# Is $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] trustworthy?

Tags: php, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)
>   [Is $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] always isset()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187714/is-serverremote-addr-always-isset)

Well, I'd like to know if `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` always contains the IP of the transmitter of the http request? Never mind if it's a proxy, a vpn or the real client IP, does this var always contain a valid IP address, or is it alterable in any manner by the client?

Comment: Yes, it can be faked. However, it's not trivial. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092563/how-to-fake-serverremote-addr-variable#5092951

Comment: not to mention key is REMOTE_ADDR not remote_addr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will always contain the IP address of where the request came from according to the server receiving the request.

Meaning: if the request came from a computer behind a firewall/NAT/proxy, the content will be that of the firewall/NAT/proxy.