# How do I treat $_SERVER? Is it safety?

Tags: php

I can get the global ip of a client like below, but is it safety?

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’];
```

I saw some article that we have to sanitize $_GET, $_POST or $_COOKIE, but how do I treat about $_SERVER?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know PHP. It looks like `$_SERVER` only contains items generated by the server, so, other than headers (which are generated by the client), I wouldn't _think_ you'd need to sanitize it or anything.

Comment: Yes it's safe, and you can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187714/is-serverremote-addr-always-isset) about if `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will always be `isset()`

Comment: Maybe take a loot at this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092563/how-to-fake-serverremote-addr-variable.

Comment: @ZebMcCorkle `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` could very, very easily contain unsafe data. IIRC Apache will handle any unknown request method as `GET`, so `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` could contain unsafe data.

Comment: Thank you for kind answer! Some items like $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] don't contains unsafe data, but some contains, don't it? Therefore we can't fake $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], then I understood that we don't need to sanitize that value.

Comment: @masudak The user agent is an arbitrary string sent by the client, so yes, it can contain whatever.

Comment: @msanford yes, I got it. I'll have to take care of it with security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` come from user input, so they should be treated with caution.

While `$_SERVER` [is generated by PHP interpreter](http://$_SERVER%20is%20an%20array%20containing%20information%20such%20as%20headers,%20paths,%20and%20script%20locations.%20The%20entries%20in%20this%20array%20are%20created%20by%20the%20web%20server.), *it also* contains lots of user-provided data, such as `argv`, `QUERY_STRING`, `PHP_SELF`, all headers (called `HTTP_header_name`) and so on. **Treat those as unsafe user input as well.**

Never assume that it will only be a browser making a request to your server: attackers can craft special requests *very easily*.

Comment: so you mean that we should have to sanitize or do something against $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] even if it is user input data for security?